# React-JS how to prevent specific state in functional component effects of its component ( causes re-render it)

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, syntax-error, react-functional-component

I am trying to handle this issue (functional component) in declaration of State, the syntax should be like this:

const [state,setState] ==false= React.setState(0) ???

Find the right syntax for the upon State declaration regarding to make the state ineffective to its component...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

State in a functional component should be declared like this for boolean operators

```js
const [state,setState] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Appreciate your replay, but what I am trying to asking about is regarding to how I can prevent specific state cause re-rendering component in declaration step (syntax of declaration that prevent state cause render component) !!